# Why isn't my report collapsing the column, only erasing all values?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, toggle

I have a report made in SQL using Report Builder 3.0. It is a very wide report, so for ease of printing we want to allow users to collapse the columns they don't want to see. I followed a guide online but I got the toggle icon to only blank out all of the information + color underneath the header. As in, the report doesn't collapse and narrow down. It only blanks out the information. I want it to be similar to excel where you right click a column and hit hide to hide everything in that column, then everything moves over to cover what was previously there.

Comment: How many row groups do you have? At what level are you trying to toggle - the group (Group Properties > Visibility), or the row (Right click tablix > Row Visibility)? Are you toggling more than one row?

Comment: @iDrinan There are 13 row groups. I want to toggle a column but not necessarily a column group. The way I'm thinking of this is like Excel - even though there may be grouped data I only want to hide one column of the _results_.

Comment: Can you post a sample picture of the report, along with the Column Visibility options? I was able to successfully achieve your desired results by right clicking the column, selecting `Column Visibility`, and adjusting it to `Show` when initially ran and used a header textbox as my toggle item. Selecting the toggle item hid the entire column.

Comment: [Sample picture](http://imgur.com/XSFK5Dc) of how when you hit the little icon to toggle it, the column underneath gets blanked. Note that above the now blank space there are actually 2 cells, not just one. There is a tiny one above the larger one shown.

Comment: Your toggle item is set to the same column that you're trying to hide and is retaining the space because of it. Create a textbox outside of the tablix, and set that as your toggle item within the column visibility instead.

Comment: @iDrinan but the problem is that I have many columns that I want to collapse (I talked about only 1 in the question for simplicity). Let's say that I somehow put toggle icons above every column but outside the tablix. Then, when I click to collapse one, the icon might not scoot over to stay above the now collapsed column..

Comment: @iDrinan I made a textbox outside the tablix, but my column is still not collapsing. [Take a look at this screenshot](http://imgur.com/Vd5GFzn)

Comment: Interesting. What are the CanGrow and CanShrink values of the text boxes within the column set to? That shouldn't typically have any bearing, but I would recommend toying around with those values and seeing. I'm unable to recreate this issue across multiple reports and scenarios.

Comment: @iDrinan sorry for taking forever to respond. The CanGrow and CanShrink values were at True and False, respectively. I changed the CanShrink to True and nothing changed. I tried flipping the CanGrow value but again nothing worked :/